# PDF of a random variable depending on another random variable

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f_X(x), x\in\mathbb R$ and let $Y=e^X$. What is the probability density function $f_Y(y), \ y>0$ of the random variable Y?

The solution is $f_Y(y)=\frac{f_X(log(y)}{y}$ but how do I actually compute it?

The reason I am asking is so I can understand how to calculate the PDF of a random variable that depends on another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the fundamental tranformation theorem directly deriving $f_Y(y)$

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|=f_X(log(y))\cdot \frac{1}{y}$$

Proof of the theorem:

As per definition

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[g(X) \leq y]=$$

Suppose g is monotone increasing (that is  your case) we have

$$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[X \leq g^{-1}(y)]=F_X(g^{-1}(y))$$

to derive $f_Y(y)$ simply derivate F obtaining

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)$$

you can do the same brainstorming with g decreasing  and also with g non monotone getting similar results

Comment: Can you link to the fundamental tranformation theorem  used?

Comment: @handy :  unfortunately I am in a bike ride...non computer and no books with me...I am answering with cellular phone....anyway I proved it....look at the edit of my answer

Comment: Maybe state $g$ for completeness. You basically just make the switch from $X$ to $Y$ by applying the inverse of $g$ and then just derivate. That makes sense, thanks a lot for the answer, I really wanted to get all concepts used here correctly.

Comment: @ handy : here we go! https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/22/22.2

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice read.

Answer (score 2):

$P(Y \leq y)=P(X \leq \ln y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln y} f_X(t)dt$ for $y>0$.

Put $s=e^{t}$ to write the integral as $\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_X(\ln s) \frac 1  s ds$. Differentiate this to get the density as $\frac 1 y f_X(\ln y)$.

Answer (score 2):

By chain rule since $x=\log y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x$  we have

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|=\frac{f_X(\log(y))}{e^x}=\frac{f_X(\log(y))}{y}$$

For the proof, assuming wlog $g$ strictly increasing, note that for the CDF we have

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(g(X)\le y)=P(X\le g^{-1}(y))=F_X(g^{-1}(y))=F_X(x)$$

therefore

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_X(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F_X(x)\cdot \frac{dx}{dy}=f_X(x)\frac{dx}{dy}$$

Comment: Would have been nice if you put more detail into the answer. E.g. tell why you can use the chain rule.

Comment: @handy I'll add somethong on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know it's basic probability but I really wanted to be pedantic here since it's the basics. :) Sadly tommik was faster with his update.

Comment: @handy That's fine! Bye